# Find the supremum of $A=\left\{\frac{n}{n+1}\right\} n \in \mathbb{N^*}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Here is the question:

> Find the supremum of $A=\left\{\frac{n}{n+1}\right\} n \in \mathbb{N^*}$ without using limits

What I am having trouble with is proving my finding is a supremum.

My attempt:

I think/suspected that the supremum is $1$ so I tried working as follows:

Elements of the sequence go as follows:$1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5$,etc...

Since the denumerator is always greater than the numerator then one can say $1$ is an upper bound, we can show it by putting $\frac{n}{n+1}>1$ which results in $0>1$ so this is impossible

Since we showed that $1$ is an upper bound, the first condition of it being a supremum is satisfied, we still need to show that there is not any other upper bound that is smaller than it, usually how this is done is by reaching a contradiction by using something like the Archimedean property but I am not able to reach that.

Assume that $1$ is not a supremum, this means that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $1>x\geq \frac{n}{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}$

so logically, we need to show that if $x<1$ then $\frac{n}{n+1}>x$

some draft thoughts:

to reach $\frac{n}{n+1}>x$, we need $n>x(n+1)$, here is where I get stuck. I tried doing some manipulation to see where I would be able to use the archimedean property and work things out backward but I am not able to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $r\in(-\infty,1)$; I will prove that $r$ is not an upper bound of$$A=\left\{\frac n{n+1}\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}.$$If $r\leqslant0$, that's clear, since, in fact, the *every* element is greater than $r$. Otherwise, suppose that $r\in(0,1)$. Since $r<1$ and $r>0$, $\frac{1-r}r>0$. So, by the Archimedean property, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n<\frac{1-r}r$. But\begin{align}\frac1n<\frac{1-r}r&\iff r<n-nr\\&\iff(n+1)r<n\\&\iff r<\frac n{n+1}.\end{align}But $\frac n{n+1}\in A$ and so this proves that $r$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Therefore, $1$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how you thought of the $\frac{1-r}{r}>0$ set-up in the first place?

Comment: Before answering your question, I did these computations:\begin{align}\frac n{n+1}>r&\iff\frac{n+1}n<\frac1r\\&\iff1+\frac1n<\frac1r\\&\iff\frac1n<\frac1r-1=\frac{1-r}r.\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Isn't it $r\in (0,1)$? for $(1-r)/r>0$

Comment: @Surb Right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$, then we have

$$0<\frac{n}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}≤1$$

Suppose that

$$\sup\left\{\frac n{n+1}\right\}=k,\thinspace 0<k<1$$

Take $n=\left\lfloor\frac k{1-k}\right\rfloor+1$, then we get a contradiction:

$$\frac{n}{n+1}>k,\thinspace 0<k<1$$

This immediately implies,

$$\sup\left\{\frac n{n+1},\thinspace n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\right\}=1.$$